# View not Found – yii\base\ViewNotFoundException Cpanel Yii2

Tags: php, xampp, cpanel, yii2-advanced-app, shared-hosting

I have create a yii2 project which runs perfectly on my Windows localhost machine. But Since I have deployed application successfully on Cpanel Linux Shared Hosting, I am unable open the pages on my website.

The following error I am getting:

`The view file does not exist: /home/myproject/public_html/frontend/views/user-profile/create.php`

In logs I am getting this:

```
2023-02-21 18:00:58 [59.103.97.245][40][d712a0e687ae7a2077cf0b84af886c04][error][yii\base\ViewNotFoundException] yii\base\ViewNotFoundException: The view file does not exist: /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/frontend/views/user-profile/create.php in /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php:233
Stack trace:
#0 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile('/home/z5f2mu8pe...', Array, Object(frontend\controllers\UserProfileController))
#1 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(407): yii\base\View->render('create', Array, Object(frontend\controllers\UserProfileController))
#2 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/frontend/controllers/UserProfileController.php(91): yii\base\Controller->render('create', Array)
#3 [internal function]: frontend\controllers\UserProfileController->actionCreate()
#4 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#6 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction('create', Array)
#7 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('user-profile/cr...', Array)
#8 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#9 /home/z5f2mu8pem8k/public_html/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

I am not getting what to do in this situation?

Comment: hav you updated .htaccess file at server as well ?

Comment: @AqibJaved no, I uploaded the same file which I was using in `localhost xampp`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project permissions, thats the only difference that could be.

You can check the permissions using `ls -la` command

This depends on how you deploy your project because it can change file permissions making the files unreadable.

Also check if your apache or ngnix conf are the same.